# python interpreter - write code on several lines

Tags: python

Good evening, just a very simple question.

```
y = ([[0,1,2],
      [3,4,5],
      [6,7,8]])
```

into the python interpreter, to write this code I actually use 'space' a lot of times to pass a line. how to do it quicker?

Comment: Just do not use so many spaces, something like `y = ([[0,1,2], [3,4,5], [6,7,8]])` will work too, just tried it.

Comment: Alternatively, use the TAB key, that should work too.

Comment: You could use the Python Shell coming with IDLE. It supports tabbing.

Answer (score 0):

Use the backslash key:

```
>>> y = ([[0,1,2], \
...[3,4,5], \
...[6,7,8]])

>>> y
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. and didn't know how to formulate it on the navigator:D